# Generic Vector with cardinality type safety

Tags: swift, generics

I'm playing around with Swift for the first time, in particular, its generics. As a personal exercise, I'm implementing a struct to model an n-dimmensional vector, for any n.

Many vector operations are only valid for certain cardinalities. For example, adding a 2D vector to a 3D vector doesn't make much sense. Cross product can only be calculated on a pair of 3 or 7 dimensional vectors.

I'm trying to find a type-safe way of doing this, similar to [C++'s templates, which let you specify any arbitrary variable as a type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments).

This is the kind of syntax I'm looking for:

```
var vector2D = Vector<2>(1,2)
var vector3D = Vector<3>(3,4,5)
var fail = vector2D + vector3D //disallowed because of mismatched cardinality.
```

Currently, the cardinality is a struct member whose value is inferred from the number parameters to `init()`. This allows me to perform runtime checks for cardinality, but not compile-time.

Is there a way to achieve this sort of compile-time type checking?

Comment: I don't think that will be possible. But would the built-in tuples plus your own custom operators/functions do the trick?

Comment: For example `func  +(lhs:(Int,Int), rhs:(Int,Int)) -> (Int,Int){
    return (lhs.0+rhs.0,lhs.1+rhs.1)
}`

Comment: That solution doesn't scale to any arbitrary `n`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift currently does not have native dependently typed Arrays. However you can create one yourself, have a look at [this great blogpost](https://bigonotetaking.wordpress.com/2015/09/04/in-which-i-misunderstand-dependent-types/#more-649) by [@oisdk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892417/oisdk) which takes an in-depth look on this topic. With the mentioned code you can have something like this:

```
let twoLong = emptyArray() +| 1 +| 2
let twoChar = emptyArray() +| "a" +| "b"

onlySameLength(twoLong, rhs: twoChar)

let threeInts = emptyArray() +| 1 +| 2 +| 3

onlySameLength(twoLong, rhs: threeInts) // error
```

You can get the code and the post as a Playground [here](https://github.com/oisdk/ConstArray).