# Swift use value as generic

Tags: swift, generics

I could not find a way to use a value in a generic class definition instead of a class or protocol. For instance we often find a number of matrix classes like `SCNMatrix3`, `SCNMatrix4` while it'd be nicer to be able to define a more generic `Matrix<a, b>` and then do things like:

```
struct Mat<a is Int, b is Int> {
  static func * (left: Mat<i, j>, right: Mat<k, l>) -> Mat<i, l> where j == k {
    return ...
  }
}

let m = Matrix<4, 5>(...)
let n = Matrix<5, 3>(...)
let p = Matrix<2, 2>(...)
let x = m * n
let y = m * p // compiler error since size mismatch
```

What is the more elegant way to achieve the above?

Comment: Compare [Generic Vector with cardinality type safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342417/generic-vector-with-cardinality-type-safety).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift does currently not support values as generics.

Generic Value Parameters is listed as "Maybe" in the [generics manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generic-value-parameters).

You could use a code generator (like [gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/utils/gyb.py), which Apple uses for the Swift Standard Library) to generate different sized matrix structures.